# Are Apple Remote Desktop connections encrypted?

Tags: security, remote-desktop, apple-remote-desktop

Is the data transmitted between two machines during an Apple Remote Desktop session encrypted? E.g. the login password, the actual screenshare, the text typed etc.?

Comment: Remote Desktop > Preferences > Security!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

From Apple's [Tech Specifications page on Apple Remote Desktop](https://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/specs.html):

> Encrypt all communications between Apple Remote Desktop and client computers with 128-bit AES encryption, or disable encryption for data-intensive tasks

Comment: Comment deleted..